# Search for complete string

Tags: unix, grep

Below is the `mount` output on my machine:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-opt  /opt                
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var  /opt/var                 
/dev/mapper/rootvg-hello  /opt/hello
```

I want to grep for exactly `/opt`, not for `/opt*`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `grep -E` to pass an regex for filtering.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the line you are looking for ends in " /opt"? I.e. nothing at all after the "opt"?

Answer (score 0):

With the tools "grep" and with "egrep" you can use the anchor for line endings, `$`.

```
egrep " /opt$"
grep " /opt$"
```

This assumes that there is a blank before the "/opt" and nothing at all afterwards before the line end. I believe this is applicable for what you want to scan.